# WPA and WPA2 Help

Tags: wifi, wpa2, password-cracking, wpa2-psk

I'm trying to hack my own WPA and WPA2 network for learning purposes.

I used A 10 characters length password with only numbers, I know if I had to create the word  list file it will be Huge, So I decided to Give Crunch more Help by defining the 2 first number and the 2 last ones( Example 23@@@@@@43) .
This is the plan but can Anyone please help me with the Coding part , I will appreciate it 
THANKS ALREADY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`crunch 10 10 -f charset.lst lalpha-numeric -t 23@@@@@@43 > wordlist.lst`

I suggest you take a look at the man file in installation directory. If you have not already.

Comment: Thanks , what is the best way to speed up the process , since it appears in the cracking window, 180 ks\s I only have a 2 RAM laptop is there anything to do ?

Comment: Without programming knowledge you can't really speed things up. It might be possible to speed up generation by editing buffer size in crunch source code. Where letters/numbers are stored in buffer before being written to a file. You could also try to convert crunch source code to cuda this would speed up generation process however you will still be limited by the hard drive as it can only read/write so fast. Maybe rent/hire a VPS would be the way to go if your computer is not fast enough.